# How to Convert an Object into Array in magento 2

Tags: magento2, php

i Need All cms pages in an array I got All in an object but the format i got is not that I expected

```
$cms = $this->collectionFactory->create()->toOptionIdArray();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($cms->toArray());
exit();
```

these lines gave me result as

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => no-route
            [label] => 404 Not Found
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => home
            [label] => Home Page
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [value] => enable-cookies
            [label] => Enable Cookies
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [value] => privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode
            [label] => Privacy Policy
        )

)
```

but i need this something like

```
Array
(
     [
            "value" => 'no-route',
            "label" => '404 Not Found'
     ],
     [
            "value" => 'home',
            "label" => 'Home Page'
     ],
     [
            "value" => 'enable-cookies',
            "label" => 'Enable Cookies'
     ],
     [
            "value" => 'privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode',
            "label" => 'Privacy Policy'
     ],

]
```

i want to add CMS pages in a drop down

```
$options = [
            [
                'label' => __('Catagories'),
                'value' => [
                    [
                        'label' => __('Anchor Catagories'),
                        'value' => self::CATAGORIES_ANCHORED
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __('Non-Anchor Catagories'),
                        'value' => self::NON_CATAGORIES_ANCHORED
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            [
                'label' => __('All Products'),
                'value' => [
                    [
                        'label' => __('All Product Types'),
                        'value' => self::PRODUCT_ALL
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __('Simple Product'),
                        'value' => self::PRODUCT_SIMPLE
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __('Virtual Products'),
                        'value' => self::PRODUCT_VIRUAL
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __('Downloadable Products'),
                        'value' => self::PRODUCT_DOWNLOADABLE
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __('Configureable Products'),
                        'value' => self::PRODUCT_CONFIGUREABLE
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __('Grouped Products'),
                        'value' => self::PRODUCT_GROUPED
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __('Bundle Products'),
                        'value' => self::PRODUCT_BUNDLED
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            [
                'label' => __('CMS pages'),
                'value' => [


                ]
            ]
    ];
```

in the CMS pages options

Comment: I think both are same. I dont get any difference between what you get and what you want ..

Comment: @YashShah check updated question

Comment: You can code like this. $options[2]['value'] = $cms->toArray();

Comment: on toArray() getting error `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function toArray() on array`

Comment: You have written in your question that $cms->toArray() was giving you output. Have you changed anything in your code after that ?

Comment: Ohh m sorry it was only print_r($cms) only i mistakenly added that

Comment: you have an array result already, you can simply get the value and label using a foreach loop

Comment: In that case, $options[2]['value'] = $cms; should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not?

```
$cms = $this->collectionFactory->create()->toOptionArray();
            $options = [
                // your code
                [
                    'label' => __('CMS pages'),
                    'value' => $cms
                ]
            ];
```

Comment: that worked for me thank you

Answer (score 3):

**Try Foreach loop will help.**

Syntex :

```
$data = $cms->toArray();

foreach ($variable as $key => $value) 
{

}
```

let me know if anything you need.

**Thanks**

Comment: strill getting same result

Comment: try once $collection->toArray();

Comment: i tried this getting `Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function toArray() on array `

Comment: have you eddited question?

Comment: yes i just added code where i want to add these options

Comment: bro you can run foreach loop instead it will easy as per your updated question.

Comment: any sample code??

Comment: wail i am editing answer